# Passing blocks to a AFNetworking method?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

```
-(void )getDataFromServer: (NSMutableDictionary *)dict
 {

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/doSomething",MainURL ]];
 [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

 AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:dict];

 AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
 {
     _myArray = JSON;
     [_myTableView reloadData]; //Or do some other stuff that are related to the current `ViewController`
 }
 failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON)
 {
     NSLog(@"request: %@",request);
     NSLog(@"Failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
 }];

 [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
 }
```

I'm using the above code in 7 different places in one of my apps. The exact chunk of code is duplicated in 7 of my `ViewControllers`. What I normally used to do is to put the method I want to use in a NSObject class and allocate and use it when ever I need but because the above is Async and using blocks I can't just return the JSON to the `ViewController` who called it and have to copy & paste the above method in every `ViewController` I need it in.

My goal is to have the above in only one place in my app and still be able to call it from different `ViewControllers` around my app and get the data I need. 
I'd like to avoid using an observer such as `NSNotification` or `KVO` and looking for a more elegant solution. 
After some reading I noticed the possibility to pass blocks around. Is that a possible solution with the above? A code example would be appreciated.

Comment: In addition to Gabriele's answer below, you may want to avoid spinning up a new AFHTTPClient for each request.

Comment: I was editing my answer exactly for that. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factorize the API call to something like

```
+ (void)getDataFromServerWithParameters:(NSMutableDictionary *)params completion:(void (^)(id JSON))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError * error))failure {
     NSString * path = @"resources/123";
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:params];
     AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        if (completion)
            completion(JSON);
     } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON) {
        if (failure)
            failure(error);
     }];

     [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
 }
```

You can place this method in a utility class like `XYAPI` and just invoke it from your controllers like

```
 [XYAPI getDataFromServer:params completion:^(id JSON){
     // do something, for instance reload the table with a new data source
     _myArray = JSON;
     [_myTableView reloadData];
 } failure:^(NSError * error) {
    // do something
 }];
```

Also you don't need to spawn a new `AFHTTPClient` at every request. Configure and use a shared one in the `XYAPI` class. Something like

```
+ (AFHTTPClient *)httpClient {
    static AFHTTPClient * client = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.com/api/v1/"]];
        [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
    });
    return client;
}
```

Note that this implementation is already used in the above example.
`self` in the context of a class method is the class itself, so `self.httpClient` is indeed resolved at runtime as `[XYAPI httpClient]`.

Comment: Great answer! Very detailed and nicely written. I'll test it out and report back. Thanks a lot.